Shopware 6 installation
I'm trying to install Shopware 6 using Softaculous on cPanel. After installation the front end of the store is without CSS and I can't login to the backend using the credentials which I entered during the Softaculous installation setup.
Has someone similar experience or know how to fix this?
When I'm trying to install from the .phar.php file I'm getting error related to the resources.
